# Python nested list from scraping iteration not suitable to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, nested-lists

I have this code that automatically search strings in a database with Selenium and scrape the data with Beautifulsoup:

```
final_list = []
for x in short_list:
    search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('search_freetext')
    search_query.send_keys(x)
    time.sleep(2)
    search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    a = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.find_all('a',class_= 'title_link') if x.get_text().startswith(tuple(short_list))] 
    b = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.find_all('div',class_= 'dark_row regular_font')][0:len(a)]
    b = [' '.join(z.split()) for z in b]
    c = [list(pair) for pair in zip(a, b)]
    final_list.append(c)
    go_back = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/a[2]').click()
    time.sleep(2)

df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['Company', 'Country'])
```

When creating a dataframe df returns an error because 'final_list' has 20 columns instead of the 2 given.

If you print 'final_list' it's a nested list in a list:

```
[[['comp1', 'countr1'], ['comp1', 'countr2']],[['comp2', 'countr2'], ['comp2', 'countr3']]]
```

This happens because I append the variable c to 'final_list'. However, if I assign 'c' to the dataframe data, it fills the dataframe correctly but with one list only.

My question is how to append correctly each result from 1 loop, that is the 'c' variable?

Or how can I resolve the nested list in list to get the correct database, like this:

```
Company Country
0   comp France  Cedex, Meuse, France
1   comp-Abello, Inc.   Round Rock, Texas, USA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extend()` instead of `append()` so you don't nest the lists

```py
final_list.extend(c)
```

Comment: thanks! it worked. Point 2 was an error of mine when I copied the code, and inserted []